# Azure VM - the operation cannot be performed because the virtual machine is faulted

Tags: azure

Our VM has been running fine for a while but today it was in a stopped state and every attempt to restart it results in the error "The operation cannot be performed because the virtual machine is faulted."

We have resized the VM a few times as per previous posts on this same subject but it still fails to start. This is a production site so are in a bit of a bind without being able to start the VM. The last attempt to resize the VM has now just left it in a perpetual state of Starting without being able to change configuration settings or update it in any way.

If we delete the VM, can we just create it again and attach the original disk without any data loss?

Any ideas on how to figure out why it won't start?

Comment: I deleted the VM and created a new one, attaching the previous disk, and it still faults on start. I also can't re-use the old DNS name as it seems to be locked to the previously deleted VM. Arrggghhh!

Comment: Seems like their Southeast Asia data centre is down.
[link](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/service-dashboard/)

Comment: The data centre is fine because we are running other stuff in there and can create and start new VMs. It is just our original VHD that has started faulting and is unable to be started.

Comment: Resolved this by creating the entire VM from scratch again. Pretty painful really and I have no idea why the original VM started failing. We had not applied any updates or changes to the VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem on Southeast Asia datacenters.

check it here http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/service-dashboard/

Answer (score 5):

Resizing the VM typically fixes this problem too. E.g. size from A1 to A2 then (once it's done) back to A1 again.

Comment: Thanks. This fixed my problem after the outage on 19.11.2014.